# when the search function starts and the adapter is updated the custom ListView removes every thing in the list item except the matching search value

Tags: android, listview, search, filter, android-arrayadapter

[Image 1 : before any search performed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE97R.png)

[Image 2 : after search performed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ8FT.png)

```
  public class classBidAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<classBidAttributes>  
  implements Filterable {

   ArrayList<classBidAttributes> data;
   Context context;
   CustemFilrer filter;

 //------this is a snippit of my listview custom adapter related to the search/filter function----------------------------------------------------------

@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(filter == null){
        filter = new CustemFilrer();
    }
    return filter;
}

    class CustemFilrer extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0){
                constraint = constraint.toString();

                ArrayList<classBidAttributes> filter = new ArrayList<classBidAttributes>();
                for(int i =0; i<data.size();i++){
                    if(data.get(i).getTitle().contains(constraint)){

                        classBidAttributes filts = new classBidAttributes(data.get(i).getTitle());

                        filter.add(filts);

                        Toast.makeText(Context, "111"+filts, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                results.count = filter.size();
                results.values=filter;
                Toast.makeText(Context, "222"+filter.size() +" / "+filter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                results.count = data.size();
                results.values=data;
                Toast.makeText(Context, ""+data.size() +" / "+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            data.clear();
            data.addAll((ArrayList<classBidAttributes>) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

---

I'm guessing the problem is in "`data.clear()` , `notifyDataSetChanged()`" but im not sure whats wrong in here.

I've added images explaining what is happening when the search is performed.

hopfully this is every thing needed in this problem if u need to check any thing ask me.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: thanks man that was it, it worked just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is right. you are making mistake in `data.clear()`. By doing this you are clearing complete data of your adapter and adding the last search result. So next time you can't get original data to start filter again.

You should keep original data in another list to update it with your adapter data later.

Your code should be like this:

```
public class classBidAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<classBidAttributes>  
  implements Filterable {

    ArrayList<classBidAttributes> data;
    ArrayList<classBidAttributes> original= new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    CustemFilrer filter;

    public classBidAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<classBidAttributes> data){
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        original.addAll(data);
    }
}

 //------this is a snippit of my listview custom adapter related to the search/filter function----------------------------------------------------------

@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(filter == null){
        filter = new CustemFilrer();

    }
    return filter;
}

    class CustemFilrer extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0){
                constraint = constraint.toString();

                ArrayList<classBidAttributes> filter = new ArrayList<classBidAttributes>();
                for(int i =0; i<data.size();i++) {
                    if (data.get(i).getTitle().contains(constraint)) {
                        classBidAttributes filts = new classBidAttributes(data.get(i).getTitle());
                        filter.add(filts);
                        Toast.makeText(Context, "111" + filts, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                results.count = filter.size();
                results.values=filter;
                Toast.makeText(Context, "222"+filter.size() +" / "+filter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                results.count = original.size();
                results.values=original;
                Toast.makeText(Context, ""+original.size() +" / "+original, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            data.clear();
            data.addAll((ArrayList<classBidAttributes>) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: first thanks for the solution u provided it worked but still i have a weird bug that i can't explain, when i start searching when i inter the 1st char the search works fine filtering the items but when i inter the second char the image disappears and instead it displays the image Url provided from firebase, and so on if i inter the 3rd char it shows the image again, the 4th shows the Url, i don't really get the logic behind such bug, my guess is the loop, also when i search for numbers it doesn't work at all although the variable holding number as string is called inside the search adapter

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to make it work correctly with no bugs what so ever and it turned out to be the loop was the source of the problem, its best to avoid the normal for loop and instead use the foreach loop, i had to rewirte the whole code from scratch for the search adapter but as follows:

```
         public void filter(CharSequence constraint) {
           constraint = constraint.toString();

           data.clear();
           if(constraint.length() == 0){
               data.addAll(original);
           }else{
               for(classBidAttributes filts : original){
                           if(filts.getTitle().contains(constraint)
                           || filts.getbidid().contains(constraint)
                           || filts.getbid_offer().contains(constraint)
                           || filts.getCategory().contains(constraint)
                           || filts.getDescription().contains(constraint)
                           || filts.getQuantity().contains(constraint)
                           || filts.getRepetitive_requests_yes().contains(constraint)
                           || filts.getRepetitive_requests_no().contains(constraint)
                           || filts.getExpiry_date().contains(constraint)){
                       data.add(filts);
                   }

               }
           }
           notifyDataSetChanged();
       };
```

nevertheless this snippet is based on your answer :)